# Finding edges that have the property that if you follow them, you'll have to come back to the node you just left to reach the rest of the graph

Tags: python, algorithm, openstreetmap, networkx

I'm working on a travelling salesman problem with multiple salesmen, and I wish to find and mark the entrance to "pockets" (I don't know a better word, that's the problem), where if one salesman enters that pocket, there's no point of another one going in there unless it's too large a job for the first one.

These are all over the place in real street networks. If you go in *this way*, you have to come out again the same way sooner or later, because there's no other way out. There may be some inner structure, loops and branches, but no way back to the city proper except where you came in.

I don't care about sub-pockets, I just want to get a list of lists of nodes, where one of them is most of the city, and the others are all these pockets that are connected as described above to the main road network.

I'm working on a MultiDiGraph as provided by osmnx.

Comment: Would it be fair to restate the problem as looking for all the edges that if one is removed it partitions the graph?

Comment: @KevinBeck That would be what's called the bridges, right? No, that's not what I'm after, because that would include all the little subpockets and the trunks and branches of all tree structures, which I'm not interested in. I just want the "final bridge" connected to the main street network.

Comment: What defines the "main street network", as different from your separable sub-graphs?

Comment: @Prune For the sake of this problem, let's say that we're given a root node that belongs to the main street network.

Comment: Perhaps you want to cut the graph into biconnected components as described in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Biconnected_component

Answer (score 1):

Your starting point is the term [cut](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cut_%28graph_theory%29), a set of edges to remove that partitions the graph.  You're looking for any "minimal cut" of size 1.

For something as connected as street maps, I think you'll want [Karger's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karger%27s_algorithm) algorithm.  This searches for minimal cut points indirectly, by collapsing any heavily-connected set of nodes into a single node, until finally there are relatively few single-edge connections remaining.  From here, it's easier to find cuts.

Comment: Great pointers, thank you very much. I can't seem to find Karger's algorithm in networkx, not even in 2.0b2, but I found an implementation [here](https://github.com/jinhw1989/MinCutAlgo/blob/master/algo/MinCut.py).

Comment: Not every algorithm is already implemented in every language.  I'm glad you found one in a language you read.

Comment: @LauritzV.Thaulow - of course, if you manage to code it up to high quality using networkx, I'm sure they'd be interested in adding it.